# Which QBO Accounts Receivable account is the authoritative one?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have a QuickBooks Online company with multiple A/R accounts. (It was converted from some flavor of QB Desktop.) How can I use the IPP QBO API v3 to figure out which one is authoritative. Neither Invoice nor Payment objects reference the A/R account unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an invoice using the API. Then use the [QBO reports](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports) api to run a balance sheet and see which A/R account changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create on Invoice/Payment from QBO UI and retrieve the same using QBO V3 to see how those objects are referring your AR account.

Comment: Also, neither Invoices nor Payments, as retrieved with the API, reference the A/R account they touch. Bills and BillPayments reference the A/P account, but it doesn't happen on the receivables side.

Answer (score 0):

"QuickBooks Online (QBO) is not designed to work with multiple Accounts Receivable (AR) and Accounts Payable (AP) accounts.  The initial AR and AP accounts will be the default accounts. We encourage our customers to merge their accounts payable and receivable accounts. For more information on merging accounts, please see our related KnowledgeBase article  1221: How do I merge two accounts?

https://qboe.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1398/session/L3NpZC9mWkNLQXhSbC9wdGEvMQ%3D%3D/kw/change%20AR%20account/r_id/103898/sno/1

Comment: When clients convert their files to QBO files from desktop files, the conversion process leaves these extra AR accounts there. Why doesn't that process force subscribers to merge them?

Comment: We do not have this feature right now because we do not want to affect any chart of accounts data when the customer is not aware about it. However, I will pass on the feedback to the team to see if this should be taken care off during the conversion process.